# Is this sentence complete?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> The May 27 event, organized by the UK Beijing Association, the UK Society of Chinese Lawyers, and the Roundtable of Southern California Chinese-American Organizations, featured keynote speakers — including Zhu — who encouraged people to take positive action against racism and discrimination, such as reporting incidents to authorities and taking legal recourse.

I am doubt whether this sentence is complete. The subject is "the May 27 event", and it is "organized by the UK Beijing Association, the UK Society of Chinese Lawyers, and the Roundtable of Southern California Chinese-American Organizations" which is non-finite verb, I guessed "featured keynote speakers" is the predicate. But my intuition told me that it needed add something at the end of the sentence.

Comment: It seems perfectly fine to me. Also a minor mistake, _But my intuition told me that we __need to__ add something at the end of the sentence._

Comment: Can you rephrase this sentence? That is, just retain essential part.

Comment: _The May 27 event featured keynote speakers who encouraged people to take positive action against racism and discrimination, such as reporting incidents to authorities and taking legal recourse._ The main sentence is this. What are the parts of speech is beyond my scope, because I am not quite good at that. Hence I would suggest you wait for someone else to answer it.

Comment: Is "The May 27 event featured keynote speakers ...." means that "The May 27 event had ... as its special feature"?

Comment: If it had more features, then it would mean that the talks by the speakers were a special thing. However, if it was the sole feature, then it would be at the centre of everything. Feature means a special attraction of a kind. Then I must say you are thinking correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I just felt uncomfortable with the verb "feature", because its passive usage seems more naturally to me.

Comment: its can be broken down into at least 3 sentences.. comprised of a compound sentence: The subject "(is) organized by" and ALSO "featured keynote speakers", and then yet another attached sentence "Zhu"..."encouraged people"

Answer (score 1):

Subject: "The May 27 event"

(then a long parenthetical phrase)

Verb: "featured"

Object: "keynote speakers ..."

Then another parenthetical "including zhu"  and a long relative clause "who encouraged..."

This is a complete sentence

Answer (score 0):

The May 27 *event*, ... , *featured* keynote speakers ... who encouraged people to take positive action against racism ...

"event" is the subject.

"featured" is the active verb.